# putting a CSS box over an image and then removing it with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm a javascript newbie so please forgive me if this question is really basic. I'm having one problem with what I'm trying do to.

I have an image on a page.

I want to put a black box on top of the image (using CSS presumably) i.e. to conceal the image.

Then, using JavaScript, when the mouse moves over the black CSS box, the black box fades out revealing the image.

I know how to do the fade out using JavaScript, but I'm having trouble getting a CSS box on top of the image...

Thanks if you can help by telling me how to do this.

Note, in my efforts so far, I created a box using CSS and then added an image to the page, but the image just removed the CSS box.

Comment: Are you using a library to do the fade?  If you are using something like jQuery then I can have a better answer for you than shooting straight CSS.

Comment: @Levi Morrison thanks. I did a fade (actually, it's a roll up) in regular JavaScript but I would be interested in hearing your jQuery solution....

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I decided to add the black *cover* with JavaScript. This way, a JavaScript disabled user will still get to see your image.

#### HTML

```
<div id="container">
   <img src="path/to/your/image.png" alt="Hello" />
</div>
```

#### CSS

```
#container {
   position: relative;   
}

#container div {
   width: 100%;
   height: 100%;
   position: absolute;
   top: 0;
   left: 0;
   background: #000;
}
```

#### jQuery

```
$(function() {
    var container = $('#container'),
        div = $('<div />').appendTo(container);

    container.hover(function() {
        div.fadeOut(500);
    }, function() {
        div.fadeIn(500);
    });
});
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/alexdickson/vuLby/).

Comment: @alex: Oops, I missed that. :)

Comment: Yep, this is what I was going to do if jQuery was allowed.  Kudos on speed.

Comment: @Alex there's going to be multiple images on the site that I want this to happen to, but when I rollover one, I don't want the other black boxes to change. Is there an easy way to do this without giving each a separate container name and having multiple copies of the same function with different container names?

Comment: @Michael, take a look at my answer.

Comment: @Alex sorry to push my luck but is it possible to have the boxes different colors?

Comment: @Micheal Yes, give them all a different `id` attribute or add a class and specify the background image. [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/alexdickson/fyYcC/).

Answer (score 1):

You could try using the CSS z-index. [See here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/understanding_css_z-index). Please note the `position:absolute` is essential.

Here's one way of doing it. I think it might work.

1. Image at bottom layer.
2. Box on top of image layer.
3. JS to fade box.

Answer (score 1):

I created [here a sample](http://jsfiddle.net/ErickPetru/Lx9Jn/1/) doing exactly what you described.

It automatically creates the black box over all images with a class named `do-fade`. Images without it continues working without changes.

The jQuery that does all the work to you:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("img.do-fade").each(function () {
        var t = $(this);
        var d = $('<div class="black-box"></div>').insertAfter(this);
        d.css({ width: t.width(), height: t.height(), top: t.position().top });
        d.bind("mouseenter", function() {
            $(this).fadeTo("normal", 0);
        }).bind("mouseleave", function() {
            $(this).fadeTo("fast", 1);
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: This is exactly what I need because Multiple images. However, i want the boxes to be different colors. is that possible?

Comment: @Michael, if it's exactly what you need, why it isn't the accepted answer? Indeed, if you need anything else, just say so.

Comment: it's not the accepted answer because I had already accepted another answer and then I saw this. I was going to make this the accepted answer, but then the person whose answer I accepted also updated his answer (which I noticed just after I wrote my comment to your answer) to reflect my changing need, so I felt bad taking it away from him. sorry

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest fading an image onto a div with a black background containing the image from the beginning.

Answer (score 0):

put the image into a div with:

```
background: black;
```

the css for the image is (in a normal state):

```
visibility: hidden;
```

and with js, change the visibility of the image in the event you want.

..or you can try with css only:

```
div.container{
    background: black;
}
image{
    visibility: hidden;
}
image:hover{
    visibility: visible;
}
```